# Wrong path distance in Print Composer's Elevation Profile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, elevation-profile

I am trying to prepare a map for my hiking route. I have an elevation raster and the route in a shapefile. I am adding the Elevation Profile to my map layout, but the path's distance on the x-axis is wrong. More interestingly, it differs from the distance on the Elevation Profile View in the main QGIS window. I tried setting different projections both for the project and the layers, but it did not help.

I know I can copy the elevation profile from the main view, but I want to use atlas to generate maps for multiple segments of the route.

Can it be due to some wrong settings, or can that be a bug in QGIS (I am using version 3.32.1.)?

[image: QGIS elevation profile distance]